# iterm2: save all shell output and view without escape characters

Tags: iterm2

I'm using iterm2 and I want to save all my scrollback buffer. There is an option that is supposed to do this but it saves all the escape characters such that a 90% of the characters in the log are not relevant to either the output or commands I typed. How do I accomplish this?

I want this to automatically save all my shell output, even if I ssh into another box, or open another iterm2 window, restart iterm2, or use tmux.